npm run production stops at 43 percent
I'm working on this codebase that's using laravel mix and laravel 10.
npm run dev, development, watch and even hot are all running fine but npm run production stops at 43%.

I've tried all the solutions I could find on Stackoverflow and none of them is working.
Here's the log file when I run with --verbose:
0x...b16B6d717904
0 verbose cli /opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/23.1.0/bin/node /opt/homebrew/bin/npm
1 info using npm@10.9.0
2 info using node@v23.1.0
3 silly config load:file:/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/npm/npmrc
4 silly config load:file:/Users/sixtus/www/<project>/.npmrc
5 silly config load:file:/Users/sixtus/.npmrc
6 silly config load:file:/opt/homebrew/etc/npmrc
7 verbose title npm run production
8 verbose argv "run" "production" "--loglevel" "verbose"
9 verbose logfile logs-max:10 dir:/Users/sixtus/.npm/_logs/2024-11-08T18_11_14_417Z-
10 verbose logfile /Users/sixtus/.npm/_logs/2024-11-08T18_11_14_417Z-debug-0.log
11 silly logfile start cleaning logs, removing 1 files
12 silly logfile done cleaning log files
13 verbose cwd /Users/sixtus/www/<project>
14 verbose os Darwin 24.1.0
15 verbose node v23.1.0
16 verbose npm  v10.9.0
17 verbose exit 0
18 info ok


What do I have to do to reproduce this?

I can give you my package.json. I'm just tryna bundle a few js and sass files and my webpack config file, although, I don't think it's a webpack issue

I figured it out

The reason is because of the node version. The solution is to use lts. I was using the latest.
